# Cef/CefSharp stops loading at Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, angular, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have an Angular 7 client-side app that I am running both independently in a browser and within a Windows Forms application using CefSharp (v75.1.141). One of my angular services makes a call to the javascript Intl namespace:

```
    constructor() {
        console.log("FormattersService constructor start");
        try {
            this.currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-NZ", { style: "currency", currency: "NZD" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("FormattersService call to Intl.NumberFormat error", error);
        }
        console.log("FormattersService constructed...after call to Intl.NumberFormat");
    }
```

I've also tried replacing the `"en-NZ"` with the array `["en-NZ", "en-GB"]`, also `["en-NZ", "en-GB", "en"]`, and also just replacing it with `"en-GB"`, all with the same result.

While this service (which is DI into a component) is happily constructed in any browser I've tested it in, it completely bombs in my CefSharp browser form. Logging the console (via ChromiumWebBrowser.ConsoleMessage event) ends with the line:

> FormattersService constructor start

i.e. no error is caught, and it doesn't get to the end. The whole app just seems to stop and there's no explanation.

Any help with either using the Intl javascript locales in CefSharp/chromium, or using CefSharp to find out exactly what is going on?

I am aware of the cef locales, and have the en-GB.pak in a locales folder that CefSharp knows about (via CefSettings.LocalsDirPath) and have set Locale to en-GB, but I believe this is not related (i.e. just sets up the "browser" language).

Comment: Probably best to ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php making sure you post a link to this issue. CefSharp is just a wrapper.

Comment: @amaitland Have done so (https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17014&sid=114513298c3313ad7956b1a5090d89e4) . Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being an out-of-date cef `icudtl.dat` file.

Updated this and now `Intl.NumberFormat` and `val.toLocaleString` are no longer stalling load of application.